# HTML + CSS - Linked Images Appear With Underline Beside Them

Tags: html, css

Now, I have an issue with this website I am putting together. I have buttons that take the form of partially-transparent PNG image files that change to another form of the button when hovered, and back again once unhovered. For some reason, the images display a miniature link underline next to them, which pushes said images ever so slightly to the left for no reason. This, however, does not occur on Internet Explorer, but rather on Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox. I have tried the CSS method to remove the underlining from the images, and it works, but the images still continue to move slightly to the left, and it bugs my OCD. Is there a way to fix this? Here is my code...

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- START MAIN WEBSITE LAYOUT !-->
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://toontownsfunnyfarm.com/images/facebook.png"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Play for FREE! | Toontown's Funny Farm"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.toontownsfunnyfarm.com/play"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="A single-player video game loosely based off of Disney's Toontown Online. Brand new playgrounds, streets, storyline, tasks; you name it!"/>
    <meta name="description" content="A single-player video game loosely based off of Disney's Toontown Online. Brand new playgrounds, streets, storyline, tasks; you name it!"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="Toontown, Toontown's Funny Farm, Disney, Club Penguin, Toontown Online, Disney's Toontown Online, Disney Interactive"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <script>
      function imgOn (img) {
          if (document.images) {
              document.images[img].src = eval(img + "_on.src");
          }
      }
      function imgOff (img) {
          if (document.images) {
              document.images[img].src = eval(img + "_off.src");
          }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body text=#000000 link=#4477ff vlink=#4455bb alink=#ff5555
    leftmargin=0 topmargin=0 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0>
    <title>Play | Toontown's Funny Farm</title>
    <script>
      if (document.images) {
          about_btn_on = new Image();
          about_btn_on.src = "images/buttons/about_btn_lit.png";
          about_btn_off = new Image();
          about_btn_off.src = "images/buttons/about_btn.png";

          screenshots_btn_on = new Image();
          screenshots_btn_on.src = "images/buttons/screenshots_btn_lit.png";
          screenshots_btn_off = new Image();
          screenshots_btn_off.src = "images/buttons/screenshots_btn.png";

          releasenotes_btn_on = new Image();
          releasenotes_btn_on.src = "images/buttons/releasenotes_btn_lit.png";
          releasenotes_btn_off = new Image();
          releasenotes_btn_off.src = "images/buttons/releasenotes_btn.png";

          staff_btn_on = new Image();
          staff_btn_on.src = "images/buttons/staff_btn_lit.png";
          staff_btn_off = new Image();
          staff_btn_off.src = "images/buttons/staff_btn.png";

      play_btn_on = new Image();
      play_btn_on.src = "images/buttons/play_btn_rlvr.png";
      play_btn_off = new Image();
      play_btn_off.src = "images/buttons/play_btn.png";
      }
    </script>
    <font face="verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="1">
      <table width="718" align=center border=0 cellpadding="0" cellspacing=0
          bgcolor=#ffffff>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" align=left valign=top>
            <a href="index.html">
              <img src="images/header.png" draggable="false" border=0 width=718 height=312 />
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align=left valign=top>
        <table width=121 height=450 border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0
            align=left valign=top>
          <tr>
              <td valign=top align=right>
                  <br>
              <a href="about.html"
                onMouseOver="imgOn('about_btn')"
                onMouseOut="imgOff('about_btn')">
                <img border=0 src="images/buttons/about_btn.png" draggable="false" width="105" name="about_btn"/>
              </a>
              <br>
                <a href="screenshots.html"
                onMouseOver="imgOn('screenshots_btn')"
                onMouseOut="imgOff('screenshots_btn')">
                  <img border=0 src="images/buttons/screenshots_btn.png" draggable="false" width="105" name="screenshots_btn"/>
                </a>
                <br>
                <a href="release-notes.html"
                onMouseOver="imgOn('releasenotes_btn')"
                onMouseOut="imgOff('releasenotes_btn')">
                <img border=0 src="images/buttons/releasenotes_btn.png" draggable="false" width="105" name="releasenotes_btn"/>
              </a>
              <br>
              <a href="staff.html"
                onMouseOver="imgOn('staff_btn')"
                onMouseOut="imgOff('staff_btn')">
                <img border=0 src="images/buttons/staff_btn.png" draggable="false" width="105" name="staff_btn"/>
              </a>
              <br><br>
              <a href="play.html"
                onMouseOver="imgOn('play_btn')"
                onMouseOut="imgOff('play_btn')">
                <img border=0 src="images/buttons/play_btn.png" draggable="false" width="105" name="play_btn"/>
              </a>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align=center>
                <img src="images/props/seltzer_bottle_left.png" draggable="false" width="70"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          </td>
          <!-- END MAIN WEBSITE LAYOUT !-->
          <td align=center valign=top>
            <table width=430 height=538 border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 style="margin-left:30px">
              <tr>
                    <td align=left valign=top>
                        <br>
                  <h1>Download Toontown's Funny Farm</h1>
                  <hr/>
                  <font size="3">
                    <p>Thank you for downloading Toontown's Funny Farm!</p>
                  </font>

                  <font size="2">
                    <p>In order to play the game, click the download link corresponding to your current operating system below.</p>
                    <p>Remember, Toontown's Funny Farm is a fan-made singleplayer game, with no intentions of making revenue of any sort. The game is being worked on by voluntary workers and production of the game may cease at any time if necessary. Please do not pressure us into working on the game; we'll update it in our own time.</p>
                    <a href="https://www.toontownsfunnyfarm.com/FunnyFarm1.3/FF1.3_setup_windows.exe">Windows Download</a><br>
                    <a href="https://www.toontownsfunnyfarm.com/FunnyFarm1.3/FF1.3_mac_osx.zip">Mac OS X Download</a><br>
                    <a href="https://www.toontownsfunnyfarm.com/FunnyFarm1.3/funnyfarm_1.3_amd64.deb">Linux Download</a>
                  </font>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
            <td align=right valign=top>
              <table width=125 height=450 border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0
                  align=right valign=top>
                <tr>
                      <td valign=center align=center>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <img src="images/props/tart.png" draggable="false" width="100" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align=center>
                    <img src="images/props/megaphone.png" draggable="false" width="100" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
           </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="100%" border=0 cellpadding=4 cellspacing=0>
          <tr>
            <td align=center valign=center>
              <font color=#ffffff size="1">
                2016, Toontown's Funny Farm
              </font>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </font>
    </body>
  </html>
```

**CSS**

```
html { 
  background: url(images/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

**Image example of problem**

Internet Explorer: http://prntscr.com/bq0wa5

Google Chrome: http://prntscr.com/bq0wk8

Strangely enough, this issue doesn't affect the play button despite them being almost identical code.

Any help would be appreciated. Also, any suggestions to improve the backend of my website would also be appreciated. Many thanks. :)

Comment: You can just add text-decoration: none to your buttons, what you're seeing is the browser default of underlining all your hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, where to begin. You shouldn't use tables for layout, they're meant for tabular data. And elements like `<font>` were deprecated, if not eliminated, ages ago. You should be using CSS for styling.

But to answer your question, you're seeing the underlined because of whitespace in your code between the image and the closing link element `</a>`

Ex:

```
<a href="about.html"
                onMouseOver="imgOn('about_btn')"
                onMouseOut="imgOff('about_btn')">
                <img border=0 src="images/buttons/about_btn.png" draggable="false" width="105" name="about_btn"/>
              </a>
```

Remove the space and the underline disappears:

```
<a href="about.html"
                onMouseOver="imgOn('about_btn')"
                onMouseOut="imgOff('about_btn')"><img border=0 src="images/buttons/about_btn.png" draggable="false" width="105" name="about_btn"/></a>
```

Comment: This didn't do anything... :(

Comment: @CoffeetipM8 - It absolutely does. See https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/se1dp4ce/ vs https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/se1dp4ce/1/

Comment: Ah thank you, it did work after all. I was doing it wrong.